# User authentication / authorization using mobile app or QR code

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization

I would like to **build an authentication / authorizaton mobile app** that would:

**Scenario 1**

- receive auth requests from web apps when a QR code is scanned

**Scenario 2**

- receive auth requests from web apps when a user tries to login with username

If you know the platform *Binance* (https://accounts.binance.com/en/login?), you might notice the Scenario 1 I'm describing. As per the second scenario, I would like the user to write its name on an input field and receive a request on a mobile application that is "connected" with the webapp so that the user can willingly authorize oneself by means of a push notification.

Both scenarios require the user to be LOGGED IN in the mobile application, as to prove that they are who they say they are.

As per the technologies I would be using:

- **nodejs** on the backend
- **react** on the frontend
- **react native / flutter** on the mobile

Do you have any resources on the subject?

Thanks